# How to get composed DOM of Polymer Web Component?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I'm using Polymer 0.8-preview.
For example, I have the following component:

```
<dom-module name="greeting-tag">
    <template>
        <ul>
            <template repeat="{{s in salutations}}">
                <li>{{s.what}}: <input type="text" value="{{s.who}}"></li>
            </template>
        </ul>
    </template>        
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'greeting-tag',
        ready: function () {
            this.salutations = [
                {what: 'Hello', who: 'World'},
                {what: 'GoodBye', who: 'DOM APIs'}
            ];
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible to get the composed DOM (as JS object or text) at some point of the component life cycle?

For the example above I would like to get

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello: <input type="text" value="World"></li>
    <li>GoodBye: <input type="text" value="DOM APIs"></li>
</ul>
```

In other words, I need the result of processed template.

Comment: _Sidenote_: whether you want to play with non-released API, keep the things up-to-date: `Polymer('greeting-tag', ...` is now supposed to be `Polymer({is: 'greeting-tag', ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer `0.8` **is not yet released**. Furthermore, there is clearly stated in [the documentation draft](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/0.8-preview/PRIMER.md#array-notification), that **array notification is in high flux**.

The code you provided has a bundle of glitches:

1. `dom-module` should be identified by `id`, not by `name`.
2. `template repeat` is **gone**. One should use `<template is='x-repeat'
   items="{{salutations}}">` instead. Since array reflection is not yet released/frozen, I eliminated it from the example code below.

Putting everything together:

```
<dom-module id="greeting-tag">
  <template>
    <p>{{caption}}</p>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'greeting-tag',
        properties: {
          caption: {
            type: String,
            reflect: true
          }
        },
        ready: function () {
          this.caption = 'Welcome here',
          console.log(this.innerHTML);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The latter will print:

```
//⇒ <p style-scope="greeting-tag">Welcome here</p>
```

AFAIK, there is no ready-to-use method to do the same with arrays yet.